# JSON Decode PHP array parsing

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

I want to get status and detail key value by parsing this array in PHP. I tried foreach but it does not work. Help me to parse this array.

JSON DECODE ARRAY TO PARS:-

```
{"status": [{"status": "403","detail": "Invalid Voucher Code.asdadsasd"}]}
```

Code:

```
foreach($result['status'] as $key => $value){
    //echo $rs['status'][0]['status'];
    echo "test";
}
```

Not even echo is printing in foreach why?

Comment: What is the `$rs` variable?

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($result);` so you can see the structure? the first status contains an array of status/detail

Comment: echo $rs->status does not seem right. echo $key or $value is what you want there, I think

Comment: var_dump for array:- 
string(74) "{"status": [{"status": "403","detail": "Invalid Voucher Code.asdadsasd"}]}"

Comment: $rs was added mistakely edited program but controll is not comming into the foreach not even test is prining any idea why?

Comment: _"var_dump for array:- string(74)..."_? it's a string.

Comment: You mention JSON Decode, did you `json_decode()`???

Comment: Either `echo $value->status;` or `echo $value['status']`, depending on whether you used the second argument to `json_decode()`.

Comment: @ganeshmore That's a dump of the original JSON string, what we need to see is a dump of the result of calling `json_decode()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON text is converted to an object with an property "status" that contains a list of objects with the properties "status" and "detail".

The proper way to make the for is something like this:

```
// Starting JSON Text
$jsonText ='{"status": [{"status": "403","detail": "Invalid Voucher Code.asdadsasd"}]}';

// JSON text converted to Object
$jsonObject = json_decode($jsonText);

// Selecting the status property (that contains an array) 
// and looping each object to fetch the status and detail
foreach( $jsonObject->status as $lineObject) {
    echo $lineObject->status." ".$lineObject->detail;
}
```